# odd usage of "end" in Sample code

Tags: ruby

Looking through [this](https://github.com/rismay/w1d3_monterroza_peguero/blob/master/hangme.rb) I notice something I have never seen before on line 83.`end.map(&:chomp)` so `end` is an object? (I realize that might be 100% wrong.) Can someone explain what and how that works there? What exactly is advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full code snippet you're referring to is below:

```
def initialize(dict_file)
  @dict_arr = File.readlines(dict_file).select do |word|
    !word.include?("-") && !word.include?("'")
  end.map(&:chomp)
end
```

notice that the `end` you're talking about is the end of the block that starts on the 2nd line (it matches the `do` on line 2).

Perhaps if you see it parenthesized, and rewritten with curly braces, it will make more sense:

```
def initialize(dict_file)
  @dict_arr = (File.readlines(dict_file).select { |word|
    !word.include?("-") && !word.include?("'")
  }).map(&:chomp)
end
```

Comment: I get the parentheses, but why do you feel that it's clearer with braces instead of do...end?

Comment: The confusion was because `end` could look like a variable, whereas you can't make that mistake with an ending curly brace. (Just to be clear, I'm not advocating using curly braces instead of `do`...`end`, just highlighting the equivalence).

Answer (score 3):

No, end is not an object, but `object.some_method do ... end` is an object (or rather it's evaluated to an object) - namely the object returned by the `some_method` method.

So if you do `object.some_method do ... end.some_other_method`, you're calling `some_other_method` on the object returned by `some_method`.

Answer (score 1):

It's often helpful to examine what Ruby is doing, step-by-step. Let's see what's going with the method `ComputerPlayer#initialize`:

```
def initialize(dict_file)
  @dict_arr = File.readlines(dict_file).select do |word|
    !word.include?("-") && !word.include?("'")
  end.map(&:chomp)
end
```

First, create a file:

```
File.write("my_file", "cat\ndog's\n")
```

When we execute:

```
ComputerPlayer.new("my_file")
```

the class method [IO#readlines](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) is sent to `File`, which returns an array `a`:

```
a = File.readlines("my_file")
  #=> ["cat\n", "dog's\n"]
```

[Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) is sent to the array `a` to create an enumerator:

```
b = a.select
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["cat\n", "dog's\n"]:select>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see what it will pass to it's block:

```
b.to_a
=> ["cat\n", "dog's\n"]
```

The enumerator is invoked by sending it the method `each` with a block, and it returns an array `c`:

```
c = b.each { |word| !word.include?("-") && !word.include?("'") }
  #=> ["cat\n"]
```

Lastly, we send [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) with argument `&:chomp` (the method `String#chomp` converted to a proc) to the array `c`:

```
c.map(&:chomp)
  #=> ["cat"]
```

A final point: you can improve clarity by minimizing the use of `!`.  For example, instead of

```
...select do |word|
   !word.include?("-") && !word.include?("'")
```

consider

```
...reject do |word|
   word.include?("-") || word.include?("'")
```

You might also use a regex.